# How to remove spring security token in grails?

Tags: grails

Here for example:

```
    def test() {
        TokenStorageService.removeToken("sdfdasdsdse3we434434dfdsfdf")
        respond(data: "OK")
    }
```

Please help me!

Comment: any more information?

Comment: I used this framework : https://www.djamware.com/post/58a53b5180aca748640ce350/securing-rest-api-with-grails-3-and-spring-security-rest

Comment: But I can't logout at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't remove token if we use token storage JWT but It possible for token storage GORM. Just try this it work well.

```
String removeAccessToken(String token){

    try{
        tokenStorageService.removeToken(token)
    } catch (Exception e){
        //Exception handling code
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    return
}
```